# Associative container - exception rather than default-construct in C++

Tags: c++, allocator

I'm looking for an associative container in C++, where rather than requiring it's elements to be default-constructible, will throw an exception where a key is requested that isn't found - edit: in the appropriate functions, obviously not all of them require default-construction. This is basically because I'm replacing the Standard allocator with one that phones home and tells the master object how much memory is being allocated, and hence needs to know where "home" is.

Comment: Could you wrap the value type in another type which (a) constructs from the underlying type, (b) converts to the underlying type, (c) throws an exception in its no-args constructor? Haven't really thought it through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer for an std::map, is not using `operator[]`. Use `insert` to create the new elements and `find` to locate an existing element. If you do not use `operator[]` the contained type does not need to be default constructible, and you can decide to throw and exception if `find` does not locate the object.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [`at` members](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#id1350525-bb) of `boost::unordered_map`? These are not in `std::tr1::unordered_map`, AFAICT.